# RStudio fails to find right locale settings at startup

Tags: r, rstudio

When starting R through RStudio, the locale settings are always set wrong and R simply does not work as it should. I.e.

```
Sys.getlocale() 
> [1] "C"
```

When starting R directly, e.g Rterm.exe, the locale settings get correct by default.
The dirty quickfix in RStudio is to run this line, which solves the issue for the rest of the session.

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8;LC_CTYPE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8;LC_MONETARY=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8"
```

So, the question is how to make RStudio make R start with the right settings by default?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
```

Comment: Moving the line to `.Rprofile` is one option...

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, It seems the command was issued during RStudio startup, but stil Sys.getlocale() gives only "C" and system interaction fails until the Sys.setlocale line is manulaly done after startup..